# Определить цепочку ip адресов клиента

Tags: php

Как определить цепочку ip адресов клиента?

Пробовал HTTP заголовки типа *"FORWARDED"* но, не работает
   (HTTP_X_FORWARDED, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR,
   HTTP_FORWARDED и т.д.).

При этом конечный ip адрес клиента должен быть реальным.

Comment: ответ - "никак" ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если все-таки удастся определить конечный IP пользователя, то получится что то вроде 192.168....
Никогда не стоит доверять информации об IP адресе посетителя. Даже, если используется прокси-сервер, он может быть анонимным. Если даже прокси передает реальный адрес клиента, не факт, что клиент не использует цепочку прокси. 
Стоит так же учесть, что с 1 адреса могут выходить в сеть целые города, и, наоборот, один клиент может использовать несколько IP.
Для записи всех IP адресов клиента посмотрите с помощью print_r($_SERVER) какой набор информации известен. Но ценность этой информации сомнительная.

Answer (score 1):

Единственный IP, которому хоть как-то можно доверять, находится в $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] - это IP, с которого произошло подключение к серверу, но это не значит, что это реальный IP пользователя, так как он может быть за одним или более прокси. Все остальные $_SERVER[xFORWARDx], в которых записывается IP, могут быть подделаны и в них может находится "мусор", заметно отличающийся по формату от IP-адреса. Доверять таким данным нельзя, но в случае необходимости можно хранить как доп. сведения.

Ниже код JavaScript для определения внутреннего IP-пользователя (например 192.168.1.1) - надеюсь поможет для составления максимально "полной цепочки" доп. данных о пользователе. Работает в новой версии Google Chrome (54.0.2840.87) и других браузерах, актуальных на момент написания ответа.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IP Address</title>
</head><body>

<!-- 
http://net.ipcalf.com/ 
Make the locals proud
-->


    <div>Network IP is: <span id=list>-</span>.</div><br>

    <script>

    // NOTE: window.RTCPeerConnection is "not a constructor" in FF22/23
    var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

    if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
        var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
        if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {      // FF [and now Chrome!] needs a channel/stream to proceed
            rtc.createDataChannel('', {reliable:false});
        };

        rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
            // convert the candidate to SDP so we can run it through our general parser
            // see https://twitter.com/lancestout/status/525796175425720320 for details
            if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a="+evt.candidate.candidate);
        };
        rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
            grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
            rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
        }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });


        var addrs = Object.create(null);
        addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
        function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
            if (newAddr in addrs) return;
            else addrs[newAddr] = true;
            var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function (k) { return addrs[k]; });
            document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
        }

        function grepSDP(sdp) {
            var hosts = [];
            sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) { // c.f. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#page-39
                if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {     // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.13
                    var parts = line.split(' '),        // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-15.1
                        addr = parts[4],
                        type = parts[7];
                    if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
                } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {       // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.7
                    var parts = line.split(' '),
                        addr = parts[2];
                    updateDisplay(addr);
                }
            });
        }
    })(); else {
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";
        document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.";
    }

    </script>



    </body></html>
```